# node js, setting up versions of routes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to setup different versions for whenever I update a route in node js with out breaking previous version.

what I'm trying:

**index.js:**

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(json());
app.use(authChecker);

require('./routes.js')(app, 'v1');  <-- this line
require('./routes.js')(app, 'v2');  <-- and this line

http.createServer(app).listen(4080);
console.log('Listening on port 4080...');
...
```

**routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function(app, version) {

    console.log("version", version);

    var
    IO_ADU = require('./' + version + '/io-add-or-update.js'),
    IO_ADD = require('./' + version + '/io-add.js'),
    IO_AGG = require('./' + version + '/io-aggregate.js'),
    IO_DEL = require('./' + version + '/io-delete.js'),
    IO_FIN = require('./' + version + '/io-find.js'),
    IO_UPD = require('./' + version + '/io-update.js');

    //calls

    app.post(version + '/find',       IO_FIN.find);
    app.post(version + '/aggregate',  IO_AGG.aggregate);
    app.post(version + '/add',        IO_ADD.add);
    app.post(version + '/update',     IO_UPD.update);
    app.post(version + '/delete',     IO_DEL.delete);
    app.post(version + '/addUpdate',  IO_ADU.addOrUpdateIfExist);
};
```

the response I get when calling any of these routes is:

```
{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=http://my-ip:4080/v2/addUpdate}
```

Removing version from the urls and in index.js and routes.js makes it work. But how can I make it work with a version work or something similar?

When running index.js I dont get any errors or warnings. And when I make the call to this node app I can see that the call is received, it just seems like the rout isn't found.

Any ideas?

Comment: You use `app.post` there. Is the request `get`? If so then your app doesn't handle the request at all.

Comment: Nope, its a post request. But good point though, something I miss sometimes.

Comment: Missing `"/"+` before `version` for the `app.post` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated by gillesic in the comments I missed the "/" before version.